# How to populate spinner data based on from and to dates from sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I have written a program to insert some data which also includes a column called date, so when I am inserting something the date will also be inserted at the same time.

Insertion is working perfectly, now in a different activity I have two edittexts fromdate and todate which when clicked separate datepicker will open and the selected date will be set on the respective edittext, now what I want to do is when I have finished selecting from date and to date, I want my spinner to get populated based on the date I have inserted my data.

I have tried something which is not working though.

This is the table i have created

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FINALDATA = "Create table 
            "+TABLE_NAME_FINALDATA+" (" +UID
            +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+REFERENCE_NO+" VARCHAR(200),   
            "+ACCOUNT_NAME+" VARCHAR(200), "+ACCOUNT_TYPE+" VARCHAR(100) 
            ,"+VEHICLE_NO+" VARCHAR(100), "+DRIVER_CODE+" VARCHAR(50), 
            "+DRIVER_NAME+" VARCHAR(200), "+DIESEL_TYPE+" VARCHAR(50), 
            "+DIESEL_RATE+" DOUBLE, "+DIESEL_QUANTITY+" DOUBLE, "+AMOUNT
            +" DOUBLE, "+EFFECTIVE_DATE+" VARCHAR(255), "+NO_OF_COPIES
            +" VARCHAR(10), "+TIME+" VARCHAR(255), "+TRANSACTION_ID+"  
            VARCHAR(500), "+REMARK+" VARCHAR(500), "+SYNC+" VARCHAR(20),
            "+CLIENT_CODE+" VARCHAR(255))";

private static final String DROP_TABLE_FINALDATA = "Drop table If Exists 
          "+TABLE_NAME_FINALDATA;
```

This is the query for getting the values of accountname based on dates

```
public Cursor getAccName(String fromdate, String todate) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select 
            "+DbListHelper.ACCOUNT_NAME+", "+DbListHelper.UID+
            " from " + DbListHelper.TABLE_NAME_FINALDATA + " where 
            "+DbListHelper.EFFECTIVE_DATE+"between"+DbListHelper.EFFECTIVE_DATE
                    + " = '" + fromdate + "' and " + DbListHelper.EFFECTIVE_DATE + " = '" + todate
                    + "'", null);
    return cursor;
}
```

This is the activity code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_records);
    spinnerAccountName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAccountName);
    imgBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBack);
    etFromDate = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editFromDate);
    etTodate = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editToDate);
    txtTotalCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NoOfSlips);
    txtdieselQty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DieselQuantity);
    txtdieselAmnt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Amount);
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    listHelper = new SqliteVehicleDetails(getBaseContext());
    listHelper.open(getBaseContext());

    etFromDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
        }
    });

    etTodate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID_1);
        }
    });

    etFromDate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String fromDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.EFFECTIVE_DATE));
                String toDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.EFFECTIVE_DATE));
                cursor = listHelper.getAccName(fromDate, toDate);
                int[] to5 = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
                String[] from5 = new String[]{DbListHelper.ACCOUNT_NAME};
                final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter5 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        getBaseContext(), 
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                        cursor, 
                        from5, 
                        to5
                );
                adapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerAccountName.setAdapter(adapter5);
            }
        }
    });

    etTodate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            cursor = listHelper.getFinalData();
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String fromDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.EFFECTIVE_DATE));
                String toDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.EFFECTIVE_DATE));
                cursor = listHelper.getAccName(fromDate, toDate);
                int[] to5 = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
                String[] from5 = new String[]{DbListHelper.ACCOUNT_NAME};
                final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter5 = new
                        SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,
                        from5, to5);
                adapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerAccountName.setAdapter(adapter5);
            }
        }
    });

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog ( int id){
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_PICKER_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);

            case DATE_PICKER_ID_1:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener1, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            etFromDate.setText(selectedDay + " / " + (selectedMonth + 1) + " / " + selectedYear);
        }
    };

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            etTodate.setText(selectedDay + " / " + (selectedMonth + 1) + " / " + selectedYear);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into **date picker** as it is meant for that purpose only. A spinner is used for more of a finite choice. You can use it here but you need to do a lot of reform code to achieve the same effect.